# Class not found in path

Tags: php, testing

So I have php project and when I'm running the tests the class `TestCase` isn't found and I can't figure out why. The error in question is this: `Fatal error: Class 'project\Tests\Api\TestCase' not found in /some/path/here/test/project/Tests/Api/UsersTest.php on line 6`

The below file is named `UsersTest.php` and `TestCase` is the class that can't be found.

```
<?php

namespace project\Tests\Api;

class UsersTest extends TestCase
{
     // code here
}
```

The below file is `TestCase.php` which exists in the same folder as `UsersTest.php`

```
<?php

namespace project\Tests\Api;

abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    abstract protected function getApiClass();

    protected function getApiMock()
    {
         // code here
    }
}
```

Both of these files exists in a folder structure `test/project/Tests/Api/`. From my understanding `UsersTest.php` should be able to find the class because both of these files exist in the same namespace.

In `test/project` I have bootstrap.php file that looks like this.

```
<?php

function includeIfExists($file)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        return include $file;
    }
}

if ((!$loader = includeIfExists(__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php')) && (!$loader = includeIfExists(__DIR__.'/../../../.composer/autoload.php'))) {
    die('You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands:'.PHP_EOL.
        'curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php'.PHP_EOL.
        'php composer.phar install'.PHP_EOL);
}

$loader->add('project\Tests', __DIR__);

return $loader;
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to answer this question without some more details.  Are you using a framework?  If so, does that framework use composer for it's autoloader? If not, do you have your own class autoloader?

Comment: @watcher Not using a framework. I do use composer for the project though. And there is a bootstrap file that sits in `test/project` as you can see above.